# How to make Exe file in RCP 3.x Application using target definition and product export wizard?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, exe

My system configuration:

1. OS windows 10 64 bit
2. Eclispe Kepler
3. Eclipse RCP 3.X

I want to create ".exe" file from product export wizard so I am making a target definition from **File > Export... > Plug-in Development > Eclipse Product.**

A after creating Target Definition Location Tab-> Click on Add
[image: see this image]

I selected Software site then [image: **what is path for URL?**]

What are the plugin required to to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends what you want your target platform to be. It doesn't have to be the same release of Eclipse and can even be something quite different.

For Eclipse target platforms the site is usually something like `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/<release number>`. Where 'release number' is something like 4.5 or 4.6.

In the site there should be a 'Eclipse RCP Target Components' section where you can select 'Eclipse RCP'. This gives you a target plaform entry with the core Eclipse RCP. You might need other entries if you need more Eclipse components.

For example this is an Eclipse Neon (4.6) target:

[image]

Comment: @ greg-449 : I have put 4.4 bcz Kepler version so I select option u have mention in above screen in "Eclipse RCP".what are the next step to do for exe file generation?

Comment: That is far too broad, ask specific questions. There are plenty of help and tutorials on product export.